# AWS API Gateway: why post request body is encoded base64?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Am using API gateway to trigger a Lambda function, using Lambda Proxy integration, however the request body is encoded base64, why is that? and how can I change it to be JSON to stringify JSON?

Comment: How do you invoke the api?

Answer (score 17):

If I am understanding your question correct, you are sending non base64 encoded JSON payload as request to API gateway, however your Lambda is receiving it as base64 encoded string.

It seems that you are not setting `application/json` as your request `content-type`.
You can see in this table how API gateway decides whether `Integration Request Payload` (last column) is `Base64-encoded string` or some other type.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-workflow.html

Comment: I have the same problem and I DO set the `application/json` request `content-type`. Everything works locally (serverless offline) and when testing in the AWS console (sending a json object as body), but not when invoking via http.

Comment: I solved it @gilads, but I don't know what I did anymore :(.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem as the OP calling my API using cURL and adding the header `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` solved it for me

Comment: @morgler I had the same issue. I discovered it was because I had added "*/*" to the BinaryMediaTypes of my API gateway. Removing that fixed it.

Answer (score 11):

That's because you are using Lambda Proxy Integration in API Gateway.
If you use Lambda integration, it will be fine and you can get JSON.

Also you can change it to be JSON to stringify JSON with following method.

```
let buff = Buffer.from(event.body, "base64");
let eventBodyStr = buff.toString('UTF-8');
let eventBody = JSON.parse(eventBodyStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

API Gateway base64 encodes the request body for any content-type that is included in the "binary media types" list under API settings.

In my case a wildcard type of "*/*" was set so all requests were being base64 encoded.

The APIGatewayProxyEvent argument of your lambda handler has a property called "isBase64Encoded" that will tell you if your body has been base64 encoded by API Gateway.